# SQL Dynamic Query - Incorrect syntax near '@WhereClause'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
//_whereclause is: where (lastName like '%Davis%')
public static MyList GetAll(string _whereclause)
{         
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString))
    {
        string selectSQL = "";               
        selectSQL += "SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM [PersonnelTable]";

        if (_whereclause != string.Empty)
        {                   
            selectSQL += " @WhereClause";
        }            

        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, myConnection))
        {
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                    
            SqlParameter whereClauseParam = new SqlParameter("@WhereClause", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
            whereClauseParam.Value = _whereclause;

            myConnection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {..............
```

If I run it with the `@WhereClause` I get error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@WhereClause'.

Comment: If I change this - selectSQL += " @WhereClause"; to  selectSQL += string.Format(" Where {0}",_whereclause); then it works fine but I cannot because of SQL injection. It must be my syntax at selectSQL += " @WhereClause"; which causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your select query should be like

```
selectSQL += "SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM [PersonnelTable] where (lastName like '%" + @WhereClause + "%')";
```

Assuming that:

```
SqlParameter whereClauseParam = new SqlParameter("@WhereClause", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
whereClauseParam.Value = _whereclause;  //Here you are getting the value as 'Davis'
```

But in case you are getting the value in it as `where (lastName like '%Davis%')` then you simply need to add a space after

```
selectSQL += "SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM [PersonnelTable] ";
                                                                  ^^ here
```

Comment: Thank you. Because I am using a dynamic search criteria for _whereclause which could be: where (lastName like '%Davis%') or (firstName like '%Joe%') I have to put in the complete string into the parameter. It is working fine in my Stored Procedure and the complete string is passed in without errors like this:

Comment: @user5584794:- So you can use OR condition in query as well. Honestly speaking the where clause as parameter doesn't make much sense. You can make OR like `selectSQL += "SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM [PersonnelTable] where (lastName like '%" + @param + "%') or (firstName like ' %" + @param + "%')" ;`

Comment: Thank you I have put in the space and now I get error -An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '@WhereClause'.